# How to make Cocoa document package type with it's extension hidden by default?

Tags: cocoa, document, bundle

I'm making a Cocoa application which uses document package (bundle) as it's data.
I specified an extension and Finder now recognizes the folder with the extension as a document well.
But the folder's extension is still displaying, and I want to hide it by default (like application bundle) Is there an option to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method of `NSFileManager` to set the file attributes of any file. In this case you want to set the value of the `NSFileExtensionHidden` key.

To apply this to your saved document, you can override `-writeToURL:ofType:error:` in your `NSDocument` subclass and then set the file extension to hidden once the document is saved:

```
- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    //call super to save the file
    if(![super writeToURL:absoluteURL ofType:typeName error:outError])
        return NO;

    //get the path of the saved file
    NSString* filePath = [absoluteURL path];

    //set the file extension hidden attribute to YES
    NSDictionary* fileAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] 
                                                          forKey:NSFileExtensionHidden];
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttrs 
                                         ofItemAtPath:filePath
                                                error:outError])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this per-file approach or per-type (or extension) approach? Is that impossible setting default behavior of my file type?

Comment: This is per-file, it sets an extended attribute on the file. I don't think there's a way to set this globally.