# Finder showing document bundle extension

Tags: macos

I want to create a Document Package bundle so I added appropriate information to my application's Info.plist and created a test folder with an extension using the console. Finder shows the folder as a package/bundle with the icon I set in the plist and will try to open it in my application when I double click.

All well and good, however Finder is showing "folder.extension" even when extensions are hidden. I can remove the extension using Finder and the folder will show as the package "folder" and has a real name of "folder.extension". How can I programmatically make the folder so that Finder doesn't show the extension ?

Comment: It seems that if you add the "hide extension" bit, then I get what I'm looking for, i.e. `SetFile -a E folder.extension`. Any ideas on how to do this programmatically ?

Comment: Refer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192295/how-to-make-cocoa-document-package-type-with-its-extension-hidden-by-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in the answer mentioned by user Eonil, you can do this via [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a little Objective-C:

```
NSString *mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                                                               forKey:NSFileExtensionHidden];

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

BOOL result = [fm setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:mystring error:nil];
```